# Make POST request using Python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a POST request But getting this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 7, in <module>
    r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 87, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 266, in request
    prep = req.prepare()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 215, in prepare
    p.prepare_body(self.data, self.files)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 338, in prepare_body
    body = self._encode_params(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 74, in _encode_params
    for k, vs in to_key_val_list(data):
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

This is my program :

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.n-gal.com/index.php?route=openstock/openstock/optionStatus'

payload = {'var:1945,product_id:1126'}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

I have tried the same POST request through Advanced rest client using following data :

`URL : http://www.n-gal.com/index.php?route=openstock/openstock/optionStatus`
`payload : var=1945&product_id=1126`
`Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

And it is working fine can anyone  help me please...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.n-gal.com/index.php?route=openstock/openstock/optionStatus'

payload = 'var=1945&product_id=1126'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print r.json()
```

Answer (score 6):

You have made `payload` a [set](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset), not a dictionary. You forgot to close the string.

Change:

```
payload = {'var:1945,product_id:1126'}
```

To:

```
payload = {'var':'1945','product_id':'1126'}
```

As it is a set, the request will thus fail.

Comment: I have tried your solution but getting the same error ...what i can see from the traceback is request is failing my side actually no request is made ....i am getting error in my code there is  something wrong with my code....

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
import json

url = 'http://www.n-gal.com/index.php?route=openstock/openstock/optionStatus'

payload = {'var:1945,product_id:1126'}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old question, but I had the same problem when using Docker recently, and managed to solve it by including the `requests` library in the requirements (or just update the library with `pip install requests --upgrade`).

When using the original version of the requests library, it raised that very same error on Python3.8, which only stopped after upgrading it.